# Send email when data save in the list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, send-email

The item has been saved in the list, then email has to trigger for the  list of user in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SharePoint Designer Workflow** to send an Email on item creation in List.

For this you will need [SharePoint Designer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35491) installed on your computer.

**How to create a workflow:**

1. Open SharePoint designer.
2. Connect to your site.
3. Go to Workflows from ribbon.
4. Click **List Workflow** on ribbon and select your list.

   [image]
5. Now go to 'Workflow Settings'

   [image]
6. Setup workflow to start whenever item is created or changed(according to your requirement).

   [image]
7. Add **Send email** action.

   [image]
8. The following block will be added to your workflow:

   [image]
9. Configure 'Send email' action to use assigned to field for determining recipient emails

   [image]

   Also you can define the body for the Email. You can use different lookups there, for example inserting values from the item or item URL or whatever.
10. Publish

    [image]
11. Try adding new item to your list, you should receive email after adding an item in list.

**References**:

1. [Send e-mail in a workflow](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Out-of box feature **Alert Me** (List>Ribbon panel) or you can use workflow as given by @Ganesh if you want to send email to any specific/other user.

[image]

Comment: If you want to customize the email body template and lookup the Email receivers from list item then you have to use workflow. And if you have to send the OOTB alert email(which will be similar to display form of list item) to particular user/group(fixed) then you can use Alerts.

Comment: Yes, agree with you.